# Android SDK: findViewById(int) undefined for type

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk

This is my very first time trying to create an android app, so I've been making a lot of annoying beginner mistakes! Right now I'm just trying to create a very simple login/register system. However, I seem to be misunderstanding how to process inputs typed in by the user.
From a previous post I've seen on here, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
//in Register class
public void submission(View view){
    //Call User Constructor based on info received from Registration Activity
    EditText enteredUser = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.enteredUser);
    //then use the input from this field to do other stuff      

}
```

However for some reason, i keep getting the error that findViewById(int) is undefined for type Register (the name of the class I'm currently in). Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I have the correct import statements at the top (android.widget.EditText).

Here is the corresponding xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Register" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter New UserName:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/enteredUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

...more input buttons etc...

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPass"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:onClick = "submission" <----- Used to call the submission function after 
    android:text="Submit" />              all inputs have been filled

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for a bit of a long winded question but I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, i.e. public class Register extends Activity{} (which contains the java function i defined)

Comment: Try cleaning your project. I'm also curious, is this the only thing the IDE is saying you have an error on? Or anything Android related? @HoanNguyen this is a compile time error, findViewById() is part of Activity.

Comment: no, the tutorial i've been following did not specify whether or not I was supposed to. Where would I call this?

Comment: @A--C Yes this was the only error given by Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compile time error is because of a typo:

```
findViewbyId
```

needs to be

```
findViewById
```

Then make sure to call `setContentView()` after calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. I highly recommend following the [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) tutorial, and clearly paying attention to the code.

And as usual, [familiarize yourself with the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). If you have a compile time error, check it first, you may just have a typo!

Comment: @WakkaWakkaWakka Seems like a half-hearted effort by whoever wrote it. The Building your first app is a good source, as well as the Vogella tutorials.

Comment: Ha yeah, probably makes a lot more sense to follow the actual android tutorial. I'll check vogella as well. Thanks again!